# (ELisp) automatically nesting next line using brace return

Tags: emacs, formatting, elisp, key-bindings, auto-indent

I'm completely new to both Lisp and Emacs. In Emacs, when coding in Java for example, I want to be able to type "{" then hit "ENTER" and have the next line be ready for whatever is nested in the braces. For example, if I have the following line:

```
public void method()
```

and I type "{" then hit return I should get this:

```
public void method() {
    // indentation applied, no additional tabbing necessary
}
```

I'm already able to insert by pairs, for example, typing "{" gives "{}" with my cursor between the braces. I did this by adding these lines to the emacs init file:

```
;; insert by pairs (parens, quotes, brackets, braces)
(defun insert-pair (leftChar rightChar)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (let (
        (p1 (region-beginning))
        (p2 (region-end))
        )
    (goto-char p2)
    (insert rightChar)
    (goto-char p1)
    (insert leftChar)
    (goto-char (+ p2 2))
    )
(progn
  (insert leftChar rightChar)
  (backward-char 1) ) )
  )
(defun insert-pair-brace () (interactive) (insert-pair "{" "}") )
(global-set-key (kbd "{") 'insert-pair-brace)
```

To get the auto-nesting I described above, I added these lines:

```
;; automatically nest next line
(defun auto-nest ()
  (insert "\n\n")
  (backward-char 1)
  (insert "\t")
)
(defun auto-nest-brace () (interactive) (auto-nest) )
(global-set-key (kbd "{ RET") 'auto-nest-brace)
```

When I start up Emacs, however, I get this message:

```
error: Key sequence { RET starts with non-prefix key {
```

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it? I don't want to use a different key combination to do this. There are a lot of text editors in which this auto-nesting is standard, and it should be easy enough to code up in ELisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's great that you are trying to add this functionality to Emacs yourself, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel here. Emacs already has a command for the purpose of auto-indenting; it's called `newline-and-indent`. It is bound to <kbd>C-j</kbd> by default, but you can rebind it to <kbd>RET</kbd>

1. globally:

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
   ```
2. for a specific mode only:

   ```
   (require 'cc-mode)
   (define-key java-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
   ```

   `java-mode-map` is defined in `cc-mode.el` and not available by default, that's why you have to `require` `cc-mode` before you can modify `java-mode-map`.

---

Note that `newline-and-indent` **indents according to major mode**. That is, if you're e.g. in `java-mode` and press <kbd>RET</kbd> in some random location that's not meaningful w/r/t Java syntax, it won't insert additional whitespace at the beginning of the new line.

To read all there is to know about `newline-and-indent` do

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `newline-and-indent` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to know why I'm getting this error. I also need to have auto-nesting ONLY when a "RET" follows a "{". In short, I want Emacs to do this exactly the way Sublime or Eclipse would auto-nest.

Comment: You're trying to bind a sequence of keys when the first key itself calls a command.  That is: you set `{` to `'insert-pair-brace`, which `{` will call before you even get to the `return`.  @itsjeyd is right: you want auto-indentation via `'newline-and-indent`. (Also see the emacswiki link in the other answer.)  If you're dead set on auto-indenting ONLY after an opening brace, you could bind your return key to a function that tests for a preceding brace as so:  `(if (char-equal (char-before) ?{) (newline-and-indent) (newline))`

Comment: @Dan Thanks ;) I probably should have mentioned that `newline-and-indent` *indents according to major mode*, i.e., it will automatically Do The Right Thing depending on the current context of point...

Comment: @Occam'sBlade Please see my updated answer. Also, Dan is right about the cause of the error you are seeing^^...

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I'll implement this right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar in my emacs config which I have been using for a while. It calls `'newline-and-indent` twice then moves the point one line up before indenting correctly. Here is the snippet of code to do this from my config file:

```
;; auto indent on opening brace
(require 'cc-mode)
(defun av/auto-indent-method ()
  "Automatically indent a method by adding two newlines.
Puts point in the middle line as well as indent it by correct amount."
  (interactive)
  (newline-and-indent)
  (newline-and-indent)
  (forward-line -1)
  (c-indent-line-or-region))

(defun av/auto-indent-method-maybe ()
  "Check if point is at a closing brace then auto indent."
  (interactive)
  (let ((char-at-point (char-after (point))))
    (if (char-equal ?} char-at-point)
        (av/auto-indent-method)
      (newline-and-indent))))

(define-key java-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'av/auto-indent-method-maybe)
```

Pretty straightforward as you can see. Hopefully it will work for you. I have not used it in any other modes except java.

Comment: Awesome solution. It does what you said, but I don't get where your are specifying that this works if between braces, what sould I do I wanted it to do the same for parentheses also?

Comment: Btw I am using it globally changing `c-indent-line-or-region` to `indent-according-to-mode` and it seems to work without flaws

Comment: ohh, what a dumb question. For anyone interested: just change `(if (char-equal ?} char-at-point)` to `(if (or (char-equal ?} char-at-point) (char-equal ?) char-at-point))`

Answer (score 0):

You want a combination of auto pairs (or alternatives) plus auto indentation.  Check out the emacswiki on the former: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs

And on the latter: 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentation